# Intent putExtra() causes null pointer exception

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to run simple activity my button on click looks like this

```
public void onClick(View view){
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("TextToGive", "Hello second activity");
     startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

When I click the button I get NullPointerException no activity found.If I delete the  intent.putExtra("TextToGive", "Hello second activity");
it works, does some one know why does this happens?

Comment: Post your Log which displays ERROR.

Comment: Post the code in SecondActivity.java where you use getExtra()

Answer (score 0):

Add **SecondActivity** to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 0):

It might be work.....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you have getExtras commend in second activity?

Answer (score 0):

1st: Class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TextToGive", "Hello second activity");
startActivity(intent);
```

2nd: Class

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("TextToGive"); //Place breakpoint here notice that it contains information.
```

Side Node:

> Ensure that you have placed your activity on the android manifest file & googling problem issues like not being able to go to next activity will likely give you a quicker answer than just asking.

Comment: I also want to comment that the best way to test if you are reaching your second activity is to place a breakpoint at the beginning of onStart() or onCreate(). Good luck.